# What does "life on the road" mean?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

> To see if Golly Gollan had put a new gag into his triumph of foolery — Gollan who had been rescued from a **life on the road** by a
>   daring manager, and had been given his chance and had taken it.

Does it mean Golly Gollan was going to die and his manager had rescued him? Or he had a life passing on the road?

Comment: "Life on the road" = "a life of a person who travels a lot in order to make a living"

Comment: or a person who travels a lot because he doesn't make, or doesn't want to make,   a living.  Cf #3 *vagabond* @CowperKettle :)

Comment: Possibly easily confused with "on the streets" which specifically does mean homeless.

Answer (score 10):

*[On the road](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+road)* is an idiom, and it can mean

> on the road
>   1. On tour, as a theatrical company.
>   2. Traveling, especially as a salesperson.
>   3. Wandering, as a vagabond.

It's not easy to determine which meaning the author intends. The context is that of a theatre production, so Gollan could have been rescued from a life as an actor *on tour* (with the result that  he stayed in London) or, more drastically, from a life of wandering as a vagabond. Probably the first case.

Comment: It looks like [the book this is from was written in 1929](https://books.google.com.sl/books?id=-ztCSHZsQ60C&pg=PA12&dq=Golly+Gollan&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW3rzJi-HMAhWD1xQKHeRCDnEQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=Golly%20Gollan&f=false), and travelling entertainers were pretty common back then. Not like modern organised tours, and not vagabonds since they were working  within the law - something like buskers, who'd travel from town to town, putting on impromptu shows in venues like pubs and village halls to earn a living until it was time to move on because the locals had got bored of them.